# Having issues loading js files

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to learn how to run web application on express.js and have encountered with next problem:

1. On 2 pages (timeline, store) if I include .js files on the bottom that in 30-40% case when pages load it appears that .js libraries was not properly loaded and I the images do not display, when I duplicated the same .js libraries to the top it fixed the problem, but if I remove them from the bottom and keep only in top that also cause some other problems.
2. On other page (portfolio) if I include .js libraries only on top or bottom it mostly always cause that not all images are loaded and if I try to include them also on top i get totally blank page, in case if I include them on top or bottom

P.S: I am pretty newbie in web development but I really like it want and to learn a lot. I will very appreciate if you could help me with getting out of this issue. I've uploaded created by project to [this link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=33467900956710732130).

Comment: Is it somehow related to `express` ?

Comment: what specifically are the "problems" you see?  what do you expect to happen instead?  why do you think the problems are related to where your .js files are put in your view templates?  is there output in your browser console?  is there output in your node.js console?

Comment: @DanO, I expect the express server to load pages properly, when I completed the template for this project on my computer everything worked fine, only after loading it on express I have encountered the described problems. In my browser there is no error regarding that some files are missing. And in console it acutally show that it was able to load all .js files, but in that case what can cause that its doesn't shows other images?

Comment: I've made a photo where its show for example that I have uploaded 4 different photos to the page, but the console says it has loaded only 3, but it dispays the one that was not loaded at all. :) Link to the photo: http://postimg.org/image/dzcfy69gl/9669ed2f/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the index page only.

In **timeline/hover.js** you set the width and height of *.item-inner* by querying the *width* and *height* of the child *img*.

Or sometimes the img is not yet loaded before your javascript is executed (when your javascript scripts are at the bottom of your page). So it returns 0.

To see what is happening change **hover.js** by:

```
 $(function(){
  $('.item-inner').each(function(){
    var img = $(this).find('img');
    console.log("DEBUG", img, img.height(), img.width());
    $(this).css({height:img.height(), width:img.width()});
  })
})
```

Then check the console of your browser you'll see that when an image is not loaded at least one dimension is equal to 0.

You have to be careful of when the scripts are executed. If you want more control try to wrap your js/jquery code in:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //your code
});
```

This will wait that all your elements are fully loaded.

PS: How did I found the problem ? I first try your page with scripts at the bottom then with scripts at the top. I inspected both HTML pages and I saw that some elements had height or width set to 0. In my editor I search for the word "width" and I found where it was wrongly set.

Comment: Many many many many thanks, you've made my day! I was pretty upset for a last few days with this case. Wish you all the best and have a nice day :)